# How to make bash throw an error if -eq is used with non-numeric arguments inside [[ ... ]]?

Tags: bash, conditional-statements, arithmetic-expressions

I recently wrote a fairly complex bash script and during testing noticed a misbehavior. During analysis, I found that there was a typo where I accidentally used `-eq` instead of `==` in a conditional command, i.e. I had something like

```
[[ "$var1" -eq "$var2" ]] || { ... }
```

instead of

```
[[ "$var1" == "$var2" ]] || { ... }
```

Since in this case `var1` and `var2` could contain arbitrary strings, not only integer numbers, things went horribly wrong at that place. A quick investigation at the command line makes the problem even more clear:

```
root@cerberus:~/scripts# [[ '0' -eq '0' ]] && echo Equal
Equal
root@cerberus:~/scripts# [[ '0' -eq '1' ]] && echo Equal
root@cerberus:~/scripts# [[ 'A' -eq 'B' ]] && echo Equal
Equal
```

The last line was very surprising to me. From the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions) (at the end of the page, emphasis mine):

> arg1 OP arg2
>
> OP is one of ‘-eq’, ‘-ne’, ‘-lt’, ‘-le’, ‘-gt’, or ‘-ge’. These arithmetic binary operators return true if arg1 is equal to, not equal
> to, less than, less than or equal to, greater than, or greater than or
> equal to arg2, respectively. Arg1 and arg2 may be positive or negative
> integers. **When used with the [[ command, Arg1 and Arg2 are evaluated
> as arithmetic expressions (see Shell Arithmetic).**

Since the last line in the code above uses `-eq` with the `[[` command, `'A'` and `'B'` are evaluated as arithmetic expressions according to the citation above. The surprising thing to me was that this did not make bash throw an error, because obviously there is no reasonable method to turn `'A'` or `'B'` into an integer number.

I then tried to find out the rules which bash applies when evaluating arithmetic expressions. [The respective chapter](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html#Shell-Arithmetic) in the manual makes statements about some edge cases (e.g. expressions' expansions being `null` or `unset`), but there is nothing in it about the case where one expression's expansion is an arbitrary string which can't be evaluated arithmetically. [Note: I am aware that we shouldn't work with link-only references, but the respective sections are too long for a citation.]

Out of curiosity, I tried to find out to which arithmetic value something like `'A'` actually evaluates. This turned out to be more difficult than expected, because bash actually refuses to do "normal" arithmetic expansion on strings, even if these strings could be evaluated arithmetically:

```
root@cerberus:~/scripts# echo $(( 0 ))
0
root@cerberus:~/scripts# echo $(( '0' ))
-bash: '0' : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "'0' ")
root@cerberus:~/scripts# echo $(( 'A' ))
-bash: 'A' : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "'A' ")
```

Since I'd like to cure the problem, not the symptoms, I gave up on trying to find out the rules which bash applies when arithmetically evaluating arbitrary strings, or why it throws errors when it does this during arithmetic expansion, but not during arithmetic evaluation in conjunction with `[[`.

Instead, I now would like to know whether there is an option in bash which makes it throw an error in ***any*** situation where it must evaluate an expression arithmetically, but where this is not possible because that expression just isn't arithmetic. If there is no such option, I would like to know whether this is possible at least for the arithmetic evaluation of the arguments to `-eq`, `-ne` (and so on inside) when these operators are used inside `[[ ]]`.

Comment: It's easy: if the string is a valid identifier, bash interprets it as the name of the variable: `A=1; B=0; x=A; y=B; [[ $x -eq 1 && $y -eq 0 ]]`

Comment: You can even drop the dollar signs from $x and $y above.

Comment: Thank you very much for caring, but that actually is not the problem. The problem is that something like `[[ 'A' -eq 'B' ]]` equals to `true` and that bash does not throw an error. Or, as another example, closer to yours, `A="Foo"; B="Bar"; [[ $A -eq $B ]] && echo Equal` outputs "`Equal`" without throwing an error. I would like to have bash throw an error in that situation, because obviously neither the string "Foo" nor the string "Bar" (i.e. the expansions of `-eq`'s arguments) can be evaluated arithmetically in a reasonable way, and thus can't be compared using `-eq` inside `[[ ... ]]`.

Comment: `How to make bash throw an error if -eq is used with non-numeric arguments inside [[ … ]]?` Check it yourself if arguments are numeric.

Comment: @KamilCuk Actually, I was afraid that I would get that advice :-) I admit that this problem is not a real show stopper. However, bash throwing an error in such situations would prevent us from such typos. Your advice is good, but if we make such typos, we probably forget to check whether the arguments are numeric, too. It would add an additional layer of safety if bash would give up in such situations. This was my motivation to ask for it; I thought that I just had missed the respective option when studying the manual.

Comment: It outputs Equal only if $Foo == $Bar. Or $Foo -eq $Bar? ;-)

Comment: @choroba Now I've go it, thanks to your last comment. Then it's the recursive expansion, plus the (documented) handling of null / unset expressions: `[[ $A -eq $B ]]` expands to `[[ Foo -eq Bar ]]`; the latter is syntactically correct, because we can leave out the `$` in arithmetic context. And because `Foo` and `Bar` (as variables) are both unset, they are both evaluated to the same arithmetic value, as documented in bash's manual. Correct? If you make your last comment an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-eq` in `[[ ... ]]` evaluates its operands as arithmetic expressions, i.e. they behave like in `((...))`. Variables with or without a dollar sign are expanded, but if their expansion is a valid identifier, the variable of that name is used to produce the value to compare.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
A=foo
B=bar
for foo in 0 1 ; do
    for bar in 0 1 ; do
        if [[ A -eq B ]] ; then
            echo "$A ($foo) eq $B ($bar)"
        else
            echo "$A ($foo) ne $B ($bar)"
        fi
    done
done
```

This expansion happens recursively

```sh
#!/bin/bash
a=1 b=a c=b d=c e=d f=e g=f h=g i=h j=i k=j l=k m=l
n=m o=n p=o q=p r=q s=r t=s u=t v=u w=v x=w y=x z=y
[[ z -eq 1 ]] && echo ok
```

The recursion limit is 1024:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
(
    echo -n a=
    for var in {a..z}{a..z}{a..z} ; do
        echo $var
        echo -n $var=
    done
    echo 42
    echo '[[ a -eq 42 ]] && echo ok'
) | bash
```

Comment: Accepted and upvoted. Thank you very much, especially for mentioning the *recursive* expansion as actual reason for the behavior, in conjunction with the fact that `$` is not needed to start parameter expansion in arithmetic evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `[ ... ]` instead of `[[ ... ]]`, I think you will get the behavior you want. Given the following function:

```
check_equal() {
  if [ "$var1" -eq "$var2" ]; then
    echo equal
  else
    echo not equal
  fi
}
```

These work as expected:

```
$ var1=0 var2=0 check_equal
equal
$ var1=0 var2=1 check_equal
not equal
```

But passing a non-numeric argument results in an error message:

```
$ var1=A var2=0 check_equal
testnumbers.sh: line 2: [: A: integer expression expected
not equal
```

The downside here, of course, is that you're using a `[ ... ]` expression, which is more fragile in some ways than the bash-only `[[ ... ]]` expression.